# Does android 4.2.2 have CacheManager?

Tags: android

My old android project(with sdk 2.2.3) cannot be compiled with sdk 4.2.2, because it seems that 4.2.2 does not have "android.webkit.CacheManager".

So how would I solve it? What can be its replacement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [CacheManager](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes/android.webkit.CacheManager.html) was deprecated in API level 11, and [the following commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/f4912580e6adc90ab37b07b8108c7334f359e317) in Android 4.2.1_r1 shows that many of its APIs were removed.

A basic implementation of a replacement would be to save the file locally, along with a tag specifying the last used time. Then, after a (certain) period of time, check if the asset is too old and delete it, if true.

[This article](http://pivotallabs.com/android-image-caching/) and [this article](http://android24hours.blogspot.ca/2011/03/how-to-build-image-cache-system.html) seem to provide with example implementations. There are also plenty of libraries, as [this one](https://github.com/mitmel/Android-Image-Cache).